# How to get facebook user data using facebook graph api using php sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api

`UserId` is coming as `null`, below is the snippet for the same. require

```
'facebooksdk/src/facebook.php'
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => 'apid',  'secret' => 'secretkey',  'allowSignedRequest' => false));
$new_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($new_access_token);
var_dump($new_access_token);
$user = $facebook->getUser();var_dump($user);
```

`$user` is always `null`, what should I do now? Do I need to do any application settings

Answer (score 0):

The getUser() should return something only after a user has been logged in using facebook login into your site.. not after settings the Facebook class with the appid and secret

Maybe this could help you:
[Get user's facebook info after login using facebook php sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782951/get-users-facebook-info-after-login-using-facebook-php-sdk)